# C# WPF - Canvas MouseMove event firing even when mouse moves over child control

Tags: wpf, events, canvas, mousemove, onmousemove

How to make it so the `Canvas` `MouseMove` event only fires if my mouse is over the `Canvas` and the `Canvas` only?

I have a `TextBox` as a child of the `Canvas` and it still fires when my mouse is moving over that `TextBox`, i would like this to not happen, it should only fire when the mouse is moving over the `Canvas` background/blank space for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to make it so the canvas `MouseMove` event only fires if my mouse is over the `Canvas` and the `Canvas` only?

You can't prevent the event from being fired but you can check whether the mouse is directly over the `Canvas` area in your event handler and simply do nothing if it isn't:

```
private void Canvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (Mouse.DirectlyOver == sender)
    {
        //your code...
    }
    //else, i.e. when the mouse moves over the TextBox or another child element, do nothing
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to listen to the preview version of that event on the canvas  PreviewMouseMove and set the e.Handled = true. 
Take a look at this url
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/routed-events-overview